# Unload data to a stage with partitions "flattened"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*Note: this is about the same situation as [How to download files with GET and preserve directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72532604/2954547) One of these might be an X-Y question. I also asked on the Snowflake Community forum: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D53r0000BZbU70CQF/prevent-filename-conflicts-when-unloading-files-with-partition-by.*

I ran `COPY INTO @mystage` with `PARTITION BY` and `SINGLE = false`, creating several files in a stage with names like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| name                                                                                                       |    size | md5                              | last_modified                |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------------------------------|
| mystage/00/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_1112_4_0.snappy.parquet | 8645856 | 2e3fe0e95b3b4d39f1b2c2cd2a5e5fd3 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:40 GMT |
| mystage/01/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_712_1_0.snappy.parquet  | 8743968 | 4d59bb8cfa355c8d55f05b88aa91002f | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:44 GMT |
| mystage/02/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_1412_1_0.snappy.parquet | 9719360 | c723aae191fb46c1c83eb660e3dd41cc | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:43 GMT |
| mystage/03/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_712_2_0.snappy.parquet  | 7786640 | b63ed8a15f18cd97ed8aaeb4fea89dee | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:44 GMT |
| mystage/04/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_712_1_0.snappy.parquet  | 9249120 | 47471b0b0fb72b8d9ae5982176f29af1 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:52:00 GMT |
| mystage/05/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_612_2_0.snappy.parquet  | 9385936 | 18b286beb69b876aa3b4e08e857f69e7 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:44 GMT |
| mystage/06/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_612_2_0.snappy.parquet  | 9187536 | 2dd0e99c7fa22fe42c624e4298c9d8f1 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:58 GMT |
| mystage/07/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_712_4_0.snappy.parquet  | 8804096 | aaf089af92251957502665fb7ab144f5 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:44 GMT |
| mystage/08/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_312_5_0.snappy.parquet  | 9214480 | 7969198b4e826d791e6f99455d01d72c | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:44 GMT |
| mystage/09/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_512_5_0.snappy.parquet  | 8986608 | 159c831c75439dcdc2743dabd91a66bb | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:41 GMT |
| mystage/10/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_112_7_0.snappy.parquet  | 9063392 | 5410728fe0723f350322075f89a7e37f | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:41 GMT |
| mystage/11/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_912_7_0.snappy.parquet  | 9197600 | 68f6c4f81c3d3890a9eb269bfcde97ec | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:39 GMT |
| mystage/12/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_1512_0_0.snappy.parquet | 9613440 | 124fdd720b104d4e6a119140409454a3 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:44 GMT |
| mystage/13/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_112_6_0.snappy.parquet  | 8524336 | 17ace7467c50a89d6558a263b40f4036 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:40 GMT |
| mystage/14/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_112_5_0.snappy.parquet  | 8830192 | 83bf9a6e027e812583b69d735adda12c | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:41 GMT |
| mystage/15/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_1112_3_0.snappy.parquet | 9051568 | a75520c1713b6e4cc7a3f28ac4589f42 | Tue, 7 Jun 2022 13:51:40 GMT |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Note that there is some directory structure here. The directories `00`, `01`, etc. were created by the `COPY INTO` command.

As I described in my other question ([How to download files with GET and preserve directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72532604/2954547)), there doesn't seem to be a way to download these files in a way that preserves the directory structure. This is a problem because at least two of the files have identical "tail" names (`data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_612_2_0.snappy.parquet`), so downloading them all to the same directory causes problems.

As a workaround for the issue described in my linked question, is there any way to change how these file names are created, such that the directory names `00`, `01`, etc. are converted to filename prefixes? That is, I would want `00_data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_1112_4_0.snappy.parquet` instead of `00/data_01a4c9ff-0602-1baa-0070-30030078eb32_1112_4_0.snappy.parquet`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will meet the requirements for your workaround, but you can partition output in CSV. The docs show an example of partitioning in Parquet, but the same partitioning works for CSV export. It will follow the Parquet partitioning naming convention.

Comment: What happens when you execute a `GET` without any filenames specified from @mystage to your local drive?  Does it not recursively download everything underneath @mystage and maintain the folder structure?

Comment: @MikeWalton it recursively downloads everything underneath `@mystage`, but it does not maintain the folder structure. It dumps all the files into the directory that I specify with `file://`.